# Роль self в классе

Tags: python

Объясните, пожалуйста, простым и доступным способом роль self в классе. Общее понимание есть, но какое-то размытое.

Comment: self - это промах в дизайне языка. Вместо того, чтобы ввести указатель на объект неявно(сравни с this в js), предпочли показать лишний аргумент в методе, но дай ему любое имя кроме self - и вот ты нарушил добрый десяток best practices. То же относится к cls для статических(или классовых? никак не могу запомнить) методов

Comment: Классовых. И в дзене сказано явно, с чем я согласен. Явное лучше неявного.

Comment: Это не то явное, про которое Дзен. С вашим максимализмом можно было бы и память под объекты явно выделять/освобождать)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

На примере понять проще всего:

```
class Counter:
  def __init__(self, start):
    self.x = start
    self.self = self # сохраним self в свойстве объекта, чтобы происпектировать его позже
  def increment(that): # Это просто аргумент функции, просто принято использовать self
    that.x += 1

a = Counter(2) # вызываем __init__ чтобы создать объект, передаём start=2
print(a.x) # 2 
a.increment()
a.increment()
print(a.x) # 4
print(a, a.self) # <__main__.Counter object at 0x7f83f92e86a0> <__main__.Counter object at 0x7f83f92e86a0>
print(a.self is a) # True Т.е. self - это имя привязанное к самому объекту
print(a.self.self.self.x) # 4
```

Answer (score 5):

`self` - это обращение к самому экземпляру класса. То есть, если вы хотите объявить переменную `x` в классе, нужно использовать `self.x = ...` . (также, переменная в классе называется свойством). Если не использовать `self`, то `x` будет локальной и потом вы не сможете к ней обратиться.

Кортеж (tuple) - то же, что список (list), но его нельзя изменять после объявления (у него просто нет таких методов).

Comment: Не к классу, а его экземпляру.

Comment: Хорошо, исправлю.

Answer (score 1):

Представьте, что Вы рассказываете другому человеку (или даже самому себе) о каких-то событиях, в которых Вы принимали участие. Как Вы себя будете называть? `self`